# Python - while input doesn't work

Tags: python, input, while-loop

Why doesn't this work? I input `windows/meterpreter/reverse_tcp` and it returns the error...again

```
def shellcode():
    os.system("clear")
    print style
    print green + "  [+]Your Choose 4 | C Type Format - ShellCode Generate"
    print style
    print payload_types
    print ' '
    payload_choose = raw_input(time + white + "Choose Payload > ")
    while (payload_choose != "windows/meterpreter/reverse_tcp" or "linux/x86/meterpreter/reverse_tcp"):
        print "[-]error"
        payload_choose = raw_input(time + white + "Choose Payload > ")
    print "ok"
```

Answer (score 4):

This line:

```
while (payload_choose != "windows/meterpreter/reverse_tcp" or "linux/x86/meterpreter/reverse_tcp"):
```

probably doesn't do what you want. I think you probably meant this?

```
while payload_choose != "windows/meterpreter/reverse_tcp" and payload_choose != "linux/x86/meterpreter/reverse_tcp":
```

### Further explanation

This expression:

```
a or b
```

means "a is true or b is true".

This expression:

```
foo != 'hello' or 'goodbye'
```

means "(foo != 'hello') is true or 'goodbye' is true". In Python, a non-empty string is considered "truthy", so your original `while` loop condition is always true.

Comment: one of this.. windows/meterpreter/reverse_tcp or linux/x86/meterpreter/reverse_tcp if i put and must to choose linux/x86/meterpreter/reverse_tcp and  windows/meterpreter/reverse_tcp :/

Comment: @Inj3ct0r What? I don't understand what you're saying.

Comment: So fix your indentation? Make sure you didn't mix tabs and spaces.